# Create a document library from custom list definition with powershell

Tags: 2007, document-library, powershell, list-definition

I have a question regarding the creating a Document Library based on the custom list definition, how can I do that using the PowerShell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with following code:

```
$workspace = $web.Webs[$workspaceURL]
$guid = $workspace.Lists.Add("CustomList", "", "CustomList", "632c2951-92c7-456e-b2e0-3034b80816be", "101", "101");
$workspace.Update();
```

Add functions, you provide the name, description, another name, GUID of the feature deploying list definition, type, type

Answer (score 3):

In PowerShell you can add a [library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms411279.aspx) the same way as you would do in C# code

First you get the Web

```
$url =  "<url web>"
$web = Get-SPWeb $url
```

Then get the [template name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplate.aspx) of a definition

To determine the name you can use someting like

```
$web.ListTemplates | Select Name, BaseType
```

Then take the name. The example below takes the document library definition and add a list based on that definition

```
$template = "Document Library"
$listTemplate = $web.ListTemplates[$Template]
$listurl = "<url list>"
$description = "<description>"
$web.Lists.Add($listUrl,$description,$listTemplate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try  with the following code,

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [string]$Web,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ListTitle,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$ListUrl,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
    [string]$Description,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$Template
    )
Start-SPAssignment -Global
$SPWeb = Get-SPWeb -Identity $Web
$listTemplate = $SPWeb.ListTemplates[$Template]
$SPWeb.Lists.Add($ListUrl,$Description,$listTemplate)
$list = $SPWeb.Lists[$ListUrl] // ex: Lists["/pts/single/Pharma Docs"]
$list.Title = $ListTitle
$list.OnQuickLaunch = "True"
$list.Update()
$SPWeb.Dispose()
Stop-SPAssignment -Global
Remove-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
```

[Source](http://blogs.catapultsystems.com/dbroussard/archive/2012/08/08/create-document-libraries-and-folders-via-powershell.aspx)